# What type should I call ResponseEntity with?

Tags: java, spring

I have a controller

```
@RestController
public class BookController {
    @GetMapping("/find-by-name/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<BookEntity> findByName(@PathVariable String name) {
      ...
```

if the name is found, then in this method I return

```
return  ResponseEntity.ok(book);
```

if not, then

```
return new ResponseEntity("name= " + name + " not found", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
```

Everything works, but the compiler swears:

```
Raw use of parameterized class 'ResponseEntity' 
Unchecked assignment: 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity' to 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<BookEntity>' 
Unchecked call to 'ResponseEntity(T, HttpStatus)' as a member of raw type 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity'
```

I tried to do this (I found this option on the website [spring.io](https://spring.io))

```
public ResponseEntity<?> findByName(@PathVariable String name) {
...
return new ResponseEntity<>("name= " + name + " not found", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
```

That error is gone, but now swears on this line:

```
Generic wildcard types should not be used in return types
```

The code works in both versions, but I would like to understand how to implement it correctly.

Comment: If you can use exceptions, then you can use controller advice and totally separate the error flows from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object` as Class in your diamond operator:

```java
public ResponseEntity<Object> someMethod() {
  return new ResponseEntity<>("Some Object", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This works fine for me so far. This works because everything extends from Object.

For Error Handling I would use the RestControllerAdvice. The Method below is called, when an IllegalArgumentException reaches to the Controller method.

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestControllerErrorHandler {

  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleIllegalArgumentException(HttpServletRequest request, IllegalArgumentException e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("your error message", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
}
```

For further information take a look [here](https://dzone.com/articles/global-exception-handling-using-spring-restcontrol). This type of global exception handling is very practical when you use RuntimeExceptions in your application.

Comment: Can I see the full example? I didn't quite understand how to separate the method with errors from the main method.

Comment: Just include this class into your code and then throw a IllegalArgumentException and see what happens. I'm not realy sure if the same package is required. At my projects it is the case. You dont have to Configur anything else. It is default in spring mvc.

Answer (score 0):

`ResponseEntity` represents an HTTP response, including *headers*, *body*, and *status*.
Usually a response should contain a *body*, be it `String`, `Void` or any other object of your liking. Hence, ResponseEntity where T signifies the type of the body. For instance,

```
public ResponseEntity<ObjectType> getObjectTYpe() {
....
return new ResponseEntity<ObjectType>(response, httpstatus);
}
```

or you can use this form:

```
return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(body);
```